# R method error is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)

Tags: r, rscript

i use a R version: 3.6.3

on R version 3.6.2 it's work

The message error: Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm): is.atomic(x) is not TRUE

the method:

```
  p <- data_df %>% dplyr::summarise(p = length(Sales[Sales>0])/length(Sales)) %>% .$p
  p <- rbinom(N*L, 1, p)
  
  #--/ simulate the data
  # i mind the error is here
  data_df %>%
    filter(Sales > 0) %>%
    do(
      x = density(.$Sales, 
                  bw = bw_in, kernel = kernel_in, adjust = adjust_in)
    ) %>%
    tidy(x) %>%
    filter(x > 0) %>%
    # sample L * N probabilities
    dplyr::sample_n(size = L * N, replace = T, weight = y) %>%
    dplyr::select(x) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(sampleG = rep(c(1:N), each = L),
                  n = rep(c(1:L), times = N)) %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    mutate(x = x * p)  ->
    simulated.df
```

Comment: Can you show a small exmaple

Comment: Can you indicate which line produces the error please

Comment: @user20650 begin   data_df %>% to filter(x > 0) %>%

Comment: @pedroooo; yes there are several function calls there. Can you isolate which gives the error i.e. instead of just running  the full block of code run a section (i.e. one line) at a time and if it errors inspect the objects that were used  ... this should help you find what is causing the error